# can't pass parameters to grep from shell

Tags: macos, grep, zsh

I am trying to run a complex grep command from shell (currently zsh on MacOS, but bash would be ok)

I want to pass variables, i.e. $1 and $2, to the command : grep -e 'something $1' -e 'somethingelse $2' file

For instance my script:

```
#/bin/zsh
echo ------
echo grep -e "'"something $1"'" -e "'"somethingelse $2"'" file
echo ------
grep -e "'"something $1"'" -e "'"somethingelse $2"'" file
```

This doesn't work with:

```
% ~/scripts/test cat mouse
------
grep -e 'something cat' -e 'somethingelse mouse' file
------
grep: cat': No such file or directory
grep: mouse': No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: `I am trying to run a complex grep command` - never a good start to anything :-)! Are you trying to grep for a regexp or a string? Do you want to do partial or full line matching?

Comment: @EdMorton : According to the options used, the OP seems to want to use simple regexp.

Comment: @user1934428 there's often a big difference between what the OP is doing and what they **want** to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to add single-quotes when you run the command; just put double-quotes around the pattern (including the parameter):

```
#/bin/zsh
echo ------
echo grep -e "'something $1'" -e "'somethingelse $2'" file
echo ------
grep -e "something $1" -e "somethingelse $2" file
```

Note that when `echo`ing it, I used single-quotes inside the double-quotes. They'll be printed, so it'll *look* ok, but the shell won't treat them as syntactically significant. When actually running `grep`, you don't want single-quotes at all.

Well, unless the `something` contains escapes or dollar signs; in that case, you can either escape them:

```
grep -e "\$ometh\\ng $1" -e "\$ometh\\nge\\se $2" file
```

Or mix single- and double-quoting, with single-quotes around the fixed pattern part, and double-quotes just around the parameter part:

```
grep -e '$ometh\ng '"$1" -e '$ometh\nge\se '"$2" file
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want `grep` to see your quotes. Assuming your literal string *something* does not contain spaces or other characters which are significant to the shell (most notable filename expansion wildcards) and you are using zsh,

```
grep something$1 FILE
```

would work. Of course if you have spaces in or around your *something*, you need to quote it:

```
grep 'something '$1 FILE # Significant space between something and $1
```

or

```
grep "something $1" FILE
```

Since you also mentioned bash: In bash, only the last form (using double quotes) makes sense, because if $1 contained spaces, bash would do word splitting.